# Broadcast Receiver Still Running after app close - Android

Tags: java, android, sms, handle

I'm using some code from [this tutorial](http://webtutsdepot.com/2011/09/28/android-sdk-tutorial-how-to-receive-text-messages/) on how to receive SMS messages:

The code works perfectly, and does exactly what I want.

I am having 1 issue with it.

I want my app to run in the background, but when it's closed I want it to stop intercepting SMS messages.

My question is, why is my app still intercepting SMS messages after it's been closed?

I guess I have to find a "on close" handler and close the Broadcast Receiver then. (If there is a "on close" event handler..?).

If anyone can provide some insight I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Comment: you didn't mean app close, did you? I think you meant to minimize the app. On app close receiver wont intercept any actions ofcourse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By putting your `BroadcastReceiver` in your Manifest, it, by default, is always active. Therefore if you want it to only run while your `Activity` is shown, you'll want to enable/disable your `BroadcastReceiver` when your `Activity` resumes/pauses:

```
public void onResume()
{
    ComponentName component=new ComponentName(this, TextMessageReceiver.class);
    getPackageManager()
        .setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void onPause()
{
    ComponentName component=new ComponentName(this, TextMessageReceiver.class);
    getPackageManager()
        .setComponentEnabledSetting(component,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

The alternative, is to declare your `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` and then call `registerReceiver` and `unregisterReceiver` in the same lifecycle events.

Comment: So if we put these in MainActivity, When go to next activity, broadcast receiver will be unregistered!?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde - correct, only while the activity is running would the broadcast receiver be active.

Answer (score 0):

ive looked around on here and this is the conclusion ive come to

```
try{
        unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        Log.d("reciever",e.toString());
    }
```

i would say override onDestroy() and put it in there

Answer (score -1):

i would say override OnTerminate() on your application object and unregister your reciever there.

```
@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
    super.onTerminate();
}
```

Comment: don't use onTerminate(), 
public void onTerminate ()

Added in API level 1
This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()